# Need animation on x-axis also with css3 animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a simple programe where boll bounces on y-axis, but i don't know how to make it move on x-axis also. if i change value of x-axis transformation from 0 to positive or negative value the boll dissappears. Please, help!

```html
 

<html>
<head>
 <title>bounce</title>
 <style>
  *{margin: 0 auto;}
  div
  {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: #FFDEAD;
   border-radius: 100%;
   border:5px solid black;
   margin-top: -250px;
   animation:bounce 2s linear forwards; 
  }
  p{
   text-align: center;
   margin-top:46%;
  }
  @keyframes bounce
  {
   0%{transform:translate(0,-250px);}
   20%{transform:translate(0,450px);}
   40%{transform:translate(0,330px);}
   50%{transform:translate(0,450px);}
   65%{transform:translate(0,370px);}
   75%{transform:translate(0,450px);}
   90%{transform:translate(0,400px);}
   100%{transform:translate(0,450px);}
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div><p>this is a div</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use it and obviously you should know about the parameters of key frames attributes. You can go through this line [keyframes description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes).

```css
*{
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
div
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #FFDEAD;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border:5px solid black;
  margin-top: -250px;
  animation:bounce 2s linear forwards; 
}
p{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top:46%;
}
@keyframes bounce
{
  0%{transform:translate(0px,-250px);}
  20%{transform:translate(50px,450px);}
  40%{transform:translate(100px,330px);}  
  65%{transform:translate(200px,330px);}
  78%{transform:translate(-150px,330px);}
  90%{transform:translate(200px,330px);}
  100%{transform:translate(-20px,330px);}
}
```

```html
<div><p>this is a div</p></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use translate(tx) or translate(tx, ty)

```css
*{
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
div
{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #FFDEAD;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border:5px solid black;
  margin-top: -250px;
  animation:bounce 2s linear forwards; 
}
p{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top:46%;
}
@keyframes bounce
{
  0%{transform:translate(0px,-250px);}
  20%{transform:translate(50px,450px);}
  40%{transform:translate(100px,330px);}
  50%{transform:translate(150px,450px);}
  65%{transform:translate(200px,370px);}
  75%{transform:translate(250px,450px);}
  90%{transform:translate(300px,400px);}
  100%{transform:translate(350px,450px);}
}
```

```html
<div><p>this is a div</p></div>
```

Comment: @Harley please upvote /accept if the answer was helpful